# How to Fix Library Fail to Load Error on Eclipse?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am starting to learn how to use LWJGL. I looked on Youtube and copied a few lines of code down. When I compiled it, it worked, but when I tried to run it, it said:

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Add the directory that contains the shared library to -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath.
    b) Add the JAR that contains the shared library to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
[LWJGL] Enable the SharedLibraryLoader debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.DebugLoader=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl32.so
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:146)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:49)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccessJNI.<clinit>(MemoryAccessJNI.java:13)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Platform.mapLibraryNameBundled(Platform.java:80)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:602)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

This is the code I copied from Youtube:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to initialize GLFW!");
        }
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE,GLFW_FALSE);
        long window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Program", 0, 0);
        if (window == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create window!");
        }
        GLFWVidMode videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (videoMode.width() - 640) / 2, (videoMode.height() - 480) / 2);
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Error because you doesn't have all dependencies in your classpath. You need add the `LWJGL` jar and all its dependencies.

Try again after to overcome this error (`UnsatisfiedLinkError`).